# Looking for Errata, Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, 4th edition

Tags: reference-request, definite-integrals, integration

> This is the edition I have as a hardcover, and even though it's old, it has served me well. Except there's quite a few errors in there and I would like to know if there's a full list available somewhere?

Note: I am using the Russian edition (1963).

There's a small list [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/4196/GradshteynRyzhik.txt) found with Mathematica, but it's obviously incomplete.

In particular, I have found an error for 7.374(7):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left(-(x-y)^2 \right) H_m ( x) H_n ( x) dx=\sqrt{\pi} 2^n m! y^{n-m} L_{n}^{(n-m)} (-2y^2), \qquad n \geq m$$

According to numerical check in Mathematica, it should be:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left(-(x-y)^2 \right) H_m ( x) H_n ( x) dx=\sqrt{\pi} 2^n m! y^{n-m} L_{\color{red}{m}}^{(n-m)} (-2y^2), \qquad n \geq m$$

Which is also a particular case of 7.377, which seems to be correct:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left(-x^2 \right) H_m ( x+y) H_n ( x+z) dx=\sqrt{\pi} 2^n m! z^{n-m} L_{m}^{(n-m)} (-2yz), \qquad n \geq m$$

Comment: How is this not about math? I am asking for a reference to a list of errors in a world's most popular integrals tables...

Comment: Concerning the English editions the errata tables are maintained by Daniel Zwillinger [here](http://www.mathtable.com/gr/).

Comment: 7.374(7) remains the same in the 8th English edition

Comment: @RaymondManzoni, thank you

Comment: @JamesArathoon, oh, I'm suprised, after all these years

Comment: Glad it helped @Yuriy S! You may also be interested by the proofs provided by Moll and others in this [link](http://dauns01.math.tulane.edu/~vhm/pap-index.html) or starting from [here](http://dauns01.math.tulane.edu/~vhm/Table.html)

Comment: In the American Press Printing of 1979/1980, the index is $L_m$, so that error has been corrected in the meantime.